# Is KL divergence defined for mixed joint densities?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, information-theory

KL divergence is generally written for continuous *or* discrete densities. I am interested in the case where we have a joint density with *both* continuous and discrete variables. **If KL divergence can be defined for this case, what does it look like? What assumptions do we need?**

As an example, consider two joint densities $p(x,y)$ and $q(x,y)$, where $x\sim\operatorname{Norm}(\mu,\Sigma)$ and $y\sim\operatorname{Cat}(\rho)$. In this case, $\operatorname{Cat}(\rho)$ is the categorical distribution as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution). **What would $\operatorname{KL}(p||q)$ look like?** It is okay to assume that $x$ and $y$ are independent, or conditionally independent given their parameters, but I'd like to know if this is a necessary assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p,\,q$ are discrete distributions with the same support $\{x_i|i\in I\}$, they can be regarded as continuous using Dirac deltas. In particular, the PDF of the first distribution is $p(x)=\sum_ip_i\delta(x-x_i)$ for probability masses $p_i$. Treating $q$ similarly,$$\int_\mathbb{R}p(x)\ln\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}dx=\sum_i\int_\mathbb{R}p_i\ln\frac{p_i}{q_i}dx.$$In other words, the continuous definition of $D_\text{KL}$ (Eq. 2 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Definition)) becomes the discrete case (Eq. 1, ibid.) in the secretly-really-continuous case. So if in the mixed case we can use Dirac deltas to write a "probability density" (it will be a measure rather than a true function), we can try evaluating the integral as usual. Note, however, it might not exist, depending on where the distributions have nonzero densities.